# How to Store zip file in evernote from my app

Tags: iphone, ios, evernote

I am storing my entire data in `zip file`.
Now I want to store that `zip file` in Evernote through `my app`.

I have some samples (by google search) using those samples I can able to store an image only but I cant able to store that `zip file` in Evernote through my app.

Please help is there any way to store zip file in evernote

i am using following code to post image and its description

```
-(IBAction)authenticate:(id)sender  
{    
   EvernoteSession *session = [EvernoteSession sharedSession];  
   [session authenticateWithViewController:self completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
      if (error || !session.isAuthenticated)  
     {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:@"Could notauthenticate" delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"authenticated! noteStoreUrl:%@ webApiUrlPrefix:%@", session.noteStoreUrl, session.webApiUrlPrefix);
        }
    }];
}`
```

```
-(IBAction)Postdata:(id)sender {

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"setting_tablecell" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSData *dataHash = [myFileData md5];
    EDAMData *edamData = [[EDAMData alloc] initWithBodyHash:dataHash size:myFileData.length body:myFileData];
    EDAMResource* resource = [[EDAMResource alloc] initWithGuid:nil noteGuid:nil data:edamData mime:@"image/png" width:0 height:0 duration:0 active:0 recognition:0 attributes:nil updateSequenceNum:0 alternateData:nil];
    NSString *noteContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                             "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">"
                             "<en-note>"
                             "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Hello photo note.</span>"
                             "<br />"
                             "<span>Evernote logo :</span>"
                             "<br />"
                             "%@"
                             "</en-note>",[ENMLUtility mediaTagWithDataHash:dataHash mime:@"image/png"]];

    NSMutableArray* resources = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[resource]];
    EDAMNote *newNote = [[EDAMNote alloc] initWithGuid:nil title:@"Test photo note Nyt" content:noteContent contentHash:nil contentLength:noteContent.length created:0 updated:0 deleted:0 active:YES updateSequenceNum:0 notebookGuid:nil tagGuids:nil resources:resources attributes:nil tagNames:nil];
    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] createNote:newNote success:^(EDAMNote *note) {
        NSLog(@"Note created successfully.");
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating note : %@",error);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the mime type to "application/zip" when you create the EDAMResource object.

```
EDAMResource* resource = [[EDAMResource alloc] initWithGuid:nil noteGuid:nil data:edamData mime:@"application/zip" width:0 height:0 duration:0 active:0 recognition:0 attributes:nil updateSequenceNum:0 alternateData:nil];
```

Comment: what is best way to store sql data in everynote